# Difference between fig-8 and double triangle fundamental group

Tags: fundamental-groups, significant-figures

I know that the fundamental group of the figure 8 is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, but is there a difference between theese two?
[image]

Comment: The fundamental group of figure 8 is $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "a difference between these two"? Are you asking: "Do these two have the same fundamental group?", or are you asking "Are those two the same (i.e. homeomorphic)?"? The answers are, in that order: "yes" and "no".

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. For "but is there a difference between theese two?" i meant "but is there a difference between the fundamental grup of those two?".

Comment: @StinkingBishop do you know where I can find a proof that the fundamental group of the second image is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but a very quick search has unearthed this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem , which you should be able to apply to those two "triangles" which as the intersection have the "vertical line" - with trivial fundamental group.